# First use of headers in c and really not understanding it well

Tags: c, header

I using first time the HEADERS in c so I'm not understanding it well.

#### `main.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "kibe.h"

int main()
{
    int a[5],n,i;
    beolvas(a,n,"be.txt");
    kiir(a,n);
    return 0;
}
```

#### `kibe.h`

```
#ifndef KIBE_H_INCLUDED
#define KIBE_H_INCLUDED

void beolvas(int*, int, const char *);
void kiir(int*, int);

#endif // KIBE_H_INCLUDED
```

#### `kibe.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void beolvas(int *a,int n,const char * file)
{
    int i;
    FILE * fin;
    fin = fopen("be.txt", "rt");
    fscanf(fin,"%i",&n);
    a = (int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
    for(i = 0; i < n; ++i){
        fscanf(fin,"%i",&a[i]);
    }
    free(a);
}

void kiir(int *a,int n)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < n; ++i){
        printf("%i ",a[i]);
    }
}
```

The problem is that I get memory garbage every time and the file contains five numbers which must be read and written to monitor. If I write the `void kiir` is code to `void beolvas` function it works well.

Comment: why do you free(a) in the beolvas function? First you allocate memory for a, read the data from the file and store it into a. then u free it, before you are using it.

Comment: You could write the code with only the standard headers (all in a single file), and you would still be running into problems — your difficulties are nothing to do with the use of headers, but everything to do with the way you've written your functions.  Specifically, you allocate and then free memory in `beolvas()`, and then pass uninitialized (but still allocated) memory to `kiir()`.  That's a recipe for seeing garbage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You allocate dynamic memory in your function `beolvas` but you never pass it out of the function. Your parameters `a` and `n` have to be output parameters, so you have to change your function signature. Apart form this use `fclos` to close the file. Adapt your code like this:

*kibe.c*

```
void beolvas( int **a, int *n, const char * file )
               // ^^       ^    output paramters a and n
{
    FILE * fin;
    fin = fopen("be.txt", "rt");
    fscanf( fin, "%i", n );           // read number of elements 
                                      //   ( n is a pointer to an int ) 
    *a = malloc( *n * sizeof(int) );  // allocate memors
    for ( int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        fscanf(fin,"%i",(*a)+i);      // read one element
                                      //  ( *a is the pointer to the dynamic memory,
                                      //    so (*a)+i is a pointer to (*a)[i]  )     
    }
    fclose(fin);
}
```

*kibe.h*

```
void beolvas( int**, int* , const char *);
```

*main.c*

```
int main()
{
    int a* = NULL;
    int n = 0;
    beolvas( &a, &n,"be.txt");
          // ^   ^
    kiir( a, n );
    free(a);  // free the memory which was allocated inside function beolvas
    return 0;
}
```